# How to stop a css-animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to add a simple keyframe-animation to an element by something like that:

```
.sw_intro{
    animation: introtop;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes introtop {
    from {margin-top: 0;}
    to {margin-top: 100vh;}
}
```

But I want the end of the animation to be the end status. So, after the animation ran, the margin-top shall be 100vh not 0vh, as it currently is.

What do I need to do therefore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to `.sw_intro`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) `animation-fill-mode` is a CSS property that specifies how an animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.

If you set the value `forwards` then after animation is executed styles from the last keyframes will be applied to the target.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.